# MQTT on Azure IotHub : TLS fail on Sierra Wireless HL8548 Cellular module

Tags: azure, ssl, mqtt, tls1.2

I've trouble connecting a Sierra Wireless HL8548 Cellular module to Azure IoT Hub MQTT broker. The issue appear on TLS negociation.

I've tryed many cypher configurations (auto, those specified on Azure GitHub) but I still have the issue : **TCP Disconnection by server**

Have anyone face this kind of error ?

NB: We use Sierra Wireless Chip sockets for TCP and TLS

Comment: There should be a way to either load root CA certs into flash or skip certificate validation altogether. Check the manual. `azure-devices.net` speaks TLS 1.0/1.1/1.2 so not having common ciphers is a little far fetched but still worth checking (`openssl s_server` is a good way to check what's being negotiated).

Comment: Thx evilSnobu. I've already tried to load CA cert and deactivate CA checks but it still not working. I wonder if there's any way to get some logs of what's happening on IoT Hub side.

Comment: If you can skip cert validation try [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/). `Sierra -> stunnel on your PC -> IoT Hub`. This would give you the chance to study if the TLS handshake is what breaks or something else. Check if there's a DEBUG mode on that SoC, that would effectively give you more visibility into TLS. One more thing, are you sure you have the user/pass combo [correctly formed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly)?

Comment: Ok, I'll dig stunnel. We're already using Azure IoT Hub on thousand of devices and we never face TLS issue. Once again thx @evilSnobu for your support.

Comment: Try reaching out to [Olivier](https://twitter.com/obloch). He's a PM in Azure IoT team, i'm sure there's someone up there in Redmond already playing with that Sierra chipset and IoT Hub and maybe they can help. If you have a support plan you should definitely take advantage of that now and file a support case.